# Buildozer doesn't see Android NDK

Tags: python, android, android-ndk, kivy, buildozer

I am using Python 3.8. I want to use buildozer and Kivy to test the export to Android. However, the buldozer cannot find Android NDK. Although I specified the path in buildozer.spec, and also threw it into the buildozer folder.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you add to your question the error message (maybe with the stacktrace) and the code which caused the problem you experienced?

Comment: Same issue here